# How to reference the local host inside bash?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I am currently using the docker toolbox on Windows 10 and running boot2docker as a virtual machine. I first pulled the project bamos/openface using: `docker pull bamos/openface`. Then I ran: `docker run -it -v \Users:/Users bamos/openface /bin/bash`. Now on my Windows C:/Users, I have two images `img1` and `img2` that I need to reference inside the container's bash. However, when I entered the bash and typed `cd Users` then `ls -a`, I couldn't find the two photos. So my question is, How can I reference a file that is not In the container but is on my local host (Windows)??

Comment: What directories have you configured to be shared between the host and VM? (Note this is different from between the VM and container.) I believe you can check the settings of the VirtualBox VM.

Comment: I configured C:\Users on the host and /Users on the VM

Comment: Wait, for some reason I just restarted the machine and I can find the photos now!